# seaborn to replace a matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I am trying to make a plot with `seaborn`, of a simple plot that I have done it with `patplotlib`

```
 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    radius = [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0]
    area = [3.14159, 12.56636, 28.27431, 50.26544, 78.53975, 113.09724]
    square = [1.0, 4.0, 9.0, 16.0, 25.0, 36.0]
    plt.plot(radius, area, label='Circle')
    plt.plot(radius, square, marker='o', linestyle='--', color='r', label='Square')
    plt.xlabel('Radius/Side')
    plt.ylabel('Area')
    plt.title('Area of Shapes')
    plt.legend()
    plt.show()
```

Any idea please?

Comment: Including the IdentationError?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use it like this, your plots will look nicer as compared to default matplotlib plots :

```
import seaborn as sb
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

sb.set_style("darkgrid")
radius = [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0]
area = [3.14159, 12.56636, 28.27431, 50.26544, 78.53975, 113.09724]
square = [1.0, 4.0, 9.0, 16.0, 25.0, 36.0]
plt.plot(radius, area, label='Circle')
plt.plot(radius, square, marker='o', linestyle='--', color='r', label='Square')
plt.xlabel('Radius/Side')
plt.ylabel('Area')
plt.title('Area of Shapes')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Hope this works for you. Please keep the indentation in check though. A good resource for seaborn can be found [here](https://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/tutorial/aesthetics.html)